# Does Torque Steer damage The Car?

Tags: torque, fwd

Other than the obvious uneven/premature wear of the tires, is there any damage that torque steer may cause to the car's drivetrain or surrounding components?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

It's doubtful.  Almost all FWD cars have some amount of torque steer, unless they have equal-length CV/halfshafts - which is very difficult to package in an inexpensive car.

Even in extreme cases (flooring the accelerator from a standstill on a Cadillac Northstar V8 for instance) the vehicle is designed to deal with those forces and still be reliable.

Your hands and wrists might be another story.

Comment: My Lancia Delta has equal length shafts by use of a third dummy-shaft across the back of the engine bay.  Other than normal wear and tear it's unlikely you'll do any damage unless you torque steer yourself into a collision.

Comment: Hilarious but informative answers, thanks so much! :)